# How to avoid duplication in a VB ASP GridView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datagridview, addition

I'm working on an asp.net VB web page. I have created a grid-view which will be adding data on a button click event, but in the 1st button click event, it is added two row to the grid-view and after the 1st button click situation is normal. How can I avoid this duplication in the 1st event?

Here I attached the code and a screen print. I need to avoid the row with null values.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient 
Imports System.Collections
Partial Class add_stock
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private numOfColumns As Integer = 1
Private ctr As Integer = 0
Private tablepanel As Table = Nothing


Dim row As New TableRow()
Dim cell As New TableCell()
Dim tb9 As New Button
Dim panel2 As New Panel
Dim DT As New DataTable


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        tablepanel = New Table()
        tablepanel.ID = "tableBuild"
        Session("table") = tablepanel
        ViewState("ctr") = ctr
        'BindGridview()
    End If
    ctr = CType(ViewState("ctr"), Int32)
    tablepanel = DirectCast(Session("table"), Table)
    Panel1.Controls.Add(tablepanel)

    DT.Columns.Add("ID")
    DT.Columns.Add("Name")
    DT.Columns(0).AutoIncrement = True

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim drCurrentRow As DataRow = Nothing
    If GridView1.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        AddNewRow()
    ElseIf GridView1.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        AddNewRow()
    Else
        BindGridview()
        AddNewRow()
    End If
    'Place the table with textboxes on the page
    '-------- numOfColumns = 1
    '-------- GenerateTable(numOfColumns)
    'End of the table display with textboxes 

    ' Add row to grid view
End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "Button_Alert", "alert('Button clicked!');", True)
    numOfColumns = 1
    'Generate the Table based from the inputs
    GenerateTable(numOfColumns)
End Sub
Protected Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    GridView1.ShowFooter = True
End Sub

Protected Sub BindGridview()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    'dt.Columns.Add("rowid", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("Item Number", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Item Category", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Lead Time", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Supplier", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Item Quantity", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Re-order Level", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Unit Price", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Retails Price", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Item Details", GetType(String))
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr("Item Number") = String.Empty
    dr("Item Category") = String.Empty
    dr("Lead Time") = String.Empty
    dr("Supplier") = String.Empty
    dr("Item Quantity") = String.Empty
    dr("Re-order Level") = String.Empty
    dr("Unit Price") = String.Empty
    dr("Retails Price") = String.Empty
    dr("Item Details") = String.Empty
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    ViewState("Curtbl") = dt
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    'GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Sub AddNewRow()

    Dim rowIndex As Integer

    If ViewState("Curtbl") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("Curtbl"), DataTable)
        Dim drCurrentRow As DataRow = Nothing
        If dt.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            Dim rowcount As Integer = dt.Rows.Count
            drCurrentRow = dt.NewRow()
            '   drCurrentRow("rowid") = rowcount + 1
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Item Number") = TextBox21.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Item Category") = DropDownList4.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Lead Time") = TextBox19.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Supplier") = DropDownList3.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Item Quantity") = TextBox22.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Re-order Level") = TextBox17.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Unit Price") = TextBox23.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Retails Price") = TextBox20.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Item Details") = TextBox18.Text
            dt.Rows.Add()
            rowIndex += 1
            ViewState("Curtbl") = dt
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
            MsgBox("1st")

        ElseIf dt.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            Dim rowcount As Integer = dt.Rows.Count
            'drCurrentRow = dt.NewRow()
            '   drCurrentRow("rowid") = rowcount + 1
            MsgBox(rowcount + 1)
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Item Number") = TextBox21.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Item Category") = DropDownList4.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Lead Time") = TextBox19.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Supplier") = DropDownList3.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Item Quantity") = TextBox22.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Re-order Level") = TextBox17.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Unit Price") = TextBox23.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Retails Price") = TextBox20.Text
            dt.Rows(rowcount - 1)("Item Details") = TextBox18.Text
            dt.Rows.Add()
            rowIndex += 1

            ViewState("Curtbl") = dt
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
            MsgBox("2nd")
        Else
            Dim rowcount As Integer = dt.Rows.Count
            drCurrentRow = dt.NewRow()
            '  drCurrentRow("rowid") = rowcount + 1
            dt.Rows(1)("Item Number") = TextBox21.Text
            dt.Rows(1)("Item Category") = DropDownList4.Text
            dt.Rows(1)("Lead Time") = TextBox19.Text
            dt.Rows(1)("Supplier") = DropDownList3.Text
            dt.Rows(1)("Item Quantity") = TextBox22.Text
            dt.Rows(1)("Re-order Level") = TextBox17.Text
            dt.Rows(1)("Unit Price") = TextBox23.Text
            dt.Rows(1)("Retails Price") = TextBox20.Text
            dt.Rows(1)("Item Details") = TextBox18.Text
            dt.Rows.Add()
            rowIndex += 1
            ViewState("Curtbl") = dt
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
            MsgBox("3rd")
        End If
    Else
        Response.Write("ViewState Value is Null")
    End If

End Sub


Protected Sub OnRowDeleting(sender As Object, e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)

    Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(ViewState("Curtbl"), DataTable)
    Dim RowToDelete As Integer = e.RowIndex

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(RowToDelete)
        dt.AcceptChanges()
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
    End If
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim item As String = e.Row.Cells(0).Text
        For Each button As Button In e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
            If button.CommandName = "Delete" Then
                button.Attributes("onclick") = "if(!confirm('Do you want to delete " + item + "?')){ return false; };"
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub 
End Class
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeWLC.png)

Answer (score 0):

In above code you just need to comment  AddNewRow() method as in BindGridView() you are creating new row for table and binding that to Grid so no need to call AddNewRow() here. Please check below code.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim drCurrentRow As DataRow = Nothing
    If GridView1.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        AddNewRow()
    ElseIf GridView1.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        AddNewRow()
    Else
        BindGridview()
        'AddNewRow()
    End If
    'Place the table with textboxes on the page
    '-------- numOfColumns = 1
    '-------- GenerateTable(numOfColumns)
    'End of the table display with textboxes 

    ' Add row to grid view
End Sub
```